# Identify, group and handle objects always serialized by id separately

Tags: java, serialization, objectmapper, jackson-databind

the following setup with jackson-databind (v 2.10.3) running on Java 11.

I have the following example classes to showcase my situation: Root, Trunk Leaf. They have some back and forth references, the semantics can be ignored.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    scope = Root.class,
    property = "id")
public class Root {
  @JsonProperty
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) // Marker1
  private List<Trunk> trunks;

  public Root() {
  }

  public Root(
      String id,
      List<Trunk> trunks) {
    this.id = id;
    this.trunks = trunks;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public List<Trunk> getTrunks() {
    return trunks;
  }

  public void setTrunks(List<Trunk> trunks) {
    this.trunks = trunks;
  }
}
```

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    scope = Trunk.class,
    property = "id2")
//@JsonIdentityReference
public class Trunk {
  @JsonProperty
  private String id2;
  @JsonProperty
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Root backRoot;
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @JsonProperty
  private Trunk next;
  @JsonProperty
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Leaf leaf;

  public Trunk() {
  }

  public Trunk(
      String id2) {
    this.id2 = id2;
  }

  public Root getBackRoot() {
    return backRoot;
  }

  public void setBackRoot(Root backRoot) {
    this.backRoot = backRoot;
  }

  public Trunk getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  public void setNext(Trunk next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public Leaf getLeaf() {
    return leaf;
  }

  public void setLeaf(Leaf leaf) {
    this.leaf = leaf;
  }
}
```

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    scope = Leaf.class,
    property = "id")
public class Leaf {
  @JsonProperty
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty
  private String content;

  public Leaf() {}

  public Leaf(String id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
  }
}
```

The goal is to serialize (and later deserialize) an object graph, note that there are cycles and references appear multiple times. For example:

```
    var trunk1 = new Trunk("A");
    var trunk2 = new Trunk("N2");
    var leaf = new Leaf("LA", "38!");
    trunk1.setLeaf(leaf);
    trunk2.setLeaf(leaf);
    var test = new Root("A", List.of(trunk1, trunk2));
    trunk1.setBackRoot(test);
    trunk1.setNext(trunk2);
    trunk2.setBackRoot(test);
    trunk2.setNext(trunk2);

    String resultObjAsString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(test);
```

In the current setup resultObjAsString equals (as expected): `{"id":"A","trunks":["A","N2"]}`. If I remove the line at Marker1 the resultObjAsString equals

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "trunks": [
    {
      "id2": "A",
      "backRoot": "A",
      "next": "N2",
      "leaf": "LA"
    },
    {
      "id2": "N2",
      "backRoot": "A",
      "next": "N2",
      "leaf": "LA"
    }
  ]
}
```

as expected. As the comment in the JavaDoc for JsonIdentityReference tells us "deserialization may require additional contextual information", i.e. deserialization above outputs can of course not restore the original object graph. I'm not sure what my options here are.

What I intend to create would be the following "normalized" output:

```
{
  "root": {
    "A": {
      "id": "A",
      "trunks": [
        "A",
        "N2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "trunk": {
    "A": {
      "id2": "A",
      "backRoot": "A",
      "next": "N2",
      "leaf": "LA"
    },
    "N2": {
      "id2": "N2",
      "backRoot": "A",
      "next": "N2",
      "leaf": "LA"
    }
  },
  "leaf": {
    "LA": {
      "id": "LA",
      "content": "38!"
    }
  }
}
```

That means, while every relevant reference is stored with `alwaysAsId=true` the context is not lost but stored in the top level of the output.

I understand that it is likely not possible to create the output natively with jackson, but I would love to have a way to access all objects that were stored as references to later enumerate and store their contents separately and compile the total serialization output. In reverse I would also need a way to provide deserialized objects to relevant deserializers.